# Getting "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when using cx_Freeze even with tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll added in

Tags: python, tkinter, importerror, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert a .py file to .exe using cx_Freeze 5.1.1., but an `ImportError: DLL load failed` pops up every time I try to run the file. Based on the suggested solutions  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323533/when-using-cx-freeze-and-tkinter-i-get-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358961/cx-freeze-import-error-dll-load-failed-tkinter), I added tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll to the list of included files. They appear in the build folder, but the error message keeps popping up.

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"] = r"C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/tcl/tcl8.6"
os.environ["TK_LIBRARY"] = r"C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"


base = "Win32GUI" if sys.platform=="win32" else None


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["winsound", "random", "time", "tkinter", "math"],
"include_files": ['tcl86t.dll',
                 'tk86t.dll']}

setup(
name = "Game",
author = "Name",
description = "game description",
options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
executables = [Executable("game.py", base=base)]
)
```

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of `cx_Freeze` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1, the included modules are in a subdirectory `lib` of the build directory. The `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll` DLLs apparently need to be moved there as well.

You can do this with the following modification of your `setup.py` script:

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["winsound", "random", "time", "tkinter", "math"],
                     "include_files": [('tcl86t.dll', os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                                       ('tk86t.dll', os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this type of error occur while importing modules you can also do this:
In your setup.py add this :

```
build_exe_options = {

"packages": [],
'include_files': [],
'include_msvcr': True ## This is important
```

}