# Error when building executable from Python3.6 script importing pandas using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pandas, executable, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create a Python 3.6 executable using cx_Freeze which includes pandas and numpy. I'm using Python 3.6.5 and a virtual env created using virtualenvwrapper. I'm developing on Windows 10. cx_Freeze version is 5.1. Pandas versions is 0.23.4.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna", "os", "numpy","importlib", "pandas"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'),
         ],
    },
}

setup(
    name = "MyScript",
    options = options,
    version = "0.1",
    description = 'Placeholder desc',
    executables = executables
)
```

*Note that I manually set the env variables because they were not being found during the build process and I had to manually move the DLLs to the virtualenv folder.*

And the script looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

If I comment out the `import pandas as pd`, everything works fine. If I add the pandas import I get the following error:

```
C:\path\to\project\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>MyScript.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "MyScript.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\distutils\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    real_distutils = imp.load_module("_virtualenv_distutils", None, distutils_path, ('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "C:\path\to\Envs\MyEnv\lib\imp.py", line 217, in load_package
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 683, in _load
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I've seen a lot of forum and stack overflow questions online (actually I had to fix a lot of errors to get here) but I can't work out what cx_Freeze is missing.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled pandas, I uninstalled cx_Freeze and tried installing a previous version (install failed but that's a different SO question). I actually tried pyinstaller and py2exe but there were so many errors which were less verbose (so harder to fix) that I gave up on anything but cx_Freeze to create the executable.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Which version of `cx_Freeze` do you use, 5.1.0 or 5.1.1?

Comment: I think 5.1.1 (or whatever pip install cx_Freeze installed two days ago)

Comment: The current version of `cx_Freeze` installed by pip is 5.1.1 indeed.

Comment: Please notice that `base` is not defined in your `setup.py` example, it would be great if you can complete that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1, the included modules are in a subdirectory `lib` of the build directory. The manually added DLLs apparently need to be moved there as well.

You can do this with the following modification of your setup.py script:

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages': packages,
        'include_files': [
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'sqlite3.dll'))
        ],
    },
}
```

I'm actually not sure whether `sqlite3.dll` also needs to be moved to `lib`.

Your question is interesting in view of the fact that it seems to indicate an import conflict between `pandas` and `tkinter`. That's presumably why you get a different error message than reported in this question:
[Getting "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when using cx_Freeze even with tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll added in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52246748/8516269)

EDIT: I manage to freeze and run the OP's example script `main.py` without errors using Python 3.6.5 on Windows 7 with the following configuration

> idna 2.7 (installed with pip)
>   numpy 1.14.3+mkl (installed using [Gohlke's binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))
>   pandas 0.23.4 (installed with pip)
>   cx_Freeze 5.1.1 (installed with pip)

I use the following `setup.py` script:

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna", "os", "numpy", "importlib", "pandas"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages': packages,
        'include_files': [
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
             (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'sqlite3.dll'))
        ],
    },
}

setup(
    name="MyScript",
    options=options,
    version="0.1",
    description='Placeholder desc',
    executables=executables
)
```

Comment: I edited the setup.py script as per your answer and I can see the 3 dlls in the lib sub dir of the build directory but I'm getting the exact same error message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error message using Python 3.6.5 on Windows 7. I've added details to the answer.

Comment: The above will not work if you are working inside a virtualenv.