# cx_Freeze app closes right away with no errors

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

My `cx_Freeze` app closes when I open it and no errors print.  The setup file runs with no errors.  I believe it has something to do with imports in my main code.  I used python 3.6.5 cx_Freeze 6.0b1 and windows 10.

setup.py

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_lst = []

package_lst = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'pulp', 'pubsub', 'sqlite3', 'pandas',
               'wx', 'functools', 'sklearn', 'numpy.core._methods']

exclude_lst = ['matplotlib', 'tkinter', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt5',
               'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'sqlalchemy']

base = None

setup (
       name='test',
       version='0.01',
       author='test',
       author_email='Omitted',
       options={'build_exe':
                   {'packages': package_lst,
                    'excludes': exclude_lst,
                    'include_files': include_lst
                   }
                },
       executables=[Executable('main_.py',  base=base, icon=icon_file)]
       )
```

When I freeze this basic example it works without any issues

main.py

```
import wx


class MasterPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.createFrame()

    def createFrame(self):
        self.width, self.height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size((self.width-50, self.height-50)))
        self.SetMinSize((1080, 720))
        self.W, self.H = self.GetSize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onQuit)
        self.Centre()

    def onQuit(self, event):
        """Checks to make sure the user wants to leave the program"""
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,'Do you really want to quit?',
                           'Confirm Exit',
                            wx.ICON_QUESTION|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL )
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
    app = wx.App()
    MasterPage(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But when I add the `import pandas` or `import <any module>` above the `import wx` line the `cx_Freeze` app closes as soon as I open it

main.py

```
import pandas
import wx


class MasterPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.createFrame()

    def createFrame(self):
        self.width, self.height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size((self.width-50, self.height-50)))
        self.SetMinSize((1080, 720))
        self.W, self.H = self.GetSize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onQuit)
        self.Centre()

    def onQuit(self, event):
        """Checks to make sure the user wants to leave the program"""
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,'Do you really want to quit?',
                           'Confirm Exit',
                            wx.ICON_QUESTION|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL )
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
    app = wx.App()
    MasterPage(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have also tried to put the import in a try except statement it still will not open and no errors print

main.py

```
try:
    import pandas
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
import wx


class MasterPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.createFrame()

    def createFrame(self):
        self.width, self.height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size((self.width-50, self.height-50)))
        self.SetMinSize((1080, 720))
        self.W, self.H = self.GetSize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onQuit)
        self.Centre()

    def onQuit(self, event):
        """Checks to make sure the user wants to leave the program"""
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,'Do you really want to quit?',
                           'Confirm Exit',
                            wx.ICON_QUESTION|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL )
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
    app = wx.App()
    MasterPage(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I even included a print statement before the `import` statement and after the `import` statement the first print statement runs then the app closes.

main.py

```
print('app started')
import pandas
print('import worked')
import wx


class MasterPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.createFrame()

    def createFrame(self):
        self.width, self.height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size((self.width-50, self.height-50)))
        self.SetMinSize((1080, 720))
        self.W, self.H = self.GetSize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onQuit)
        self.Centre()

    def onQuit(self, event):
        """Checks to make sure the user wants to leave the program"""
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,'Do you really want to quit?',
                           'Confirm Exit',
                            wx.ICON_QUESTION|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL )
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
    app = wx.App()
    MasterPage(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, a similar apparent import conflict between `pandas` and `tkinter` (instead of `wx`) has been posted in [Error when building executable from Python3.6 script importing pandas using cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52248985/8516269).

1. I'm not familiar with `wx`. First of all, I think you should use `base = "Win32GUI"` for a GUI application under Windows (see the `cx_Freeze` [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#windows-command-prompt-appears-briefly)). Replace `base = None` by the following lines in your setup script:

   ```
   # GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a console application).
   import sys
   base = None
   if sys.platform == "win32":
       base = "Win32GUI"
   ```
2. As you have added `scipy` to the `packages` option list, you also need to add `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` to the `excludes` option list (see [this issue](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/233)):

   ```
   exclude_lst = ['matplotlib', 'tkinter', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt5',
                  'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'sqlalchemy',
                  'scipy.spatial.cKDTree']
   ```
3. You might also need to add `sqlite3.dll` to the `include_files` option list to be able to use `sqlite3` (I'm not sure):

   ```
   PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
   include_lst = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'sqlite3.dll'))]
   ```
4. Finally I would recommend to start your application from within a `cmd` prompt to be sure to get all error messages:

   - Start a `cmd` prompt (type `cmd` in the start menu)
   - Change to the build directory where your frozen executable has been generated
   - Start the frozen executable

If you still get any further error message, please add it to your question.

Comment: Hi Jpeg, thank you so much for all you help on this.  I was running it from the cmd prompt and it was not printing any errors it would just go to the next line.  I have add your changes and after much trail and error it came down to an Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.  The issue was since there was no error printing I could not figure out what to change.  All is good and working now.