# cx_Freeze executable not displaying matplotlib figures

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am using Python 3.5 and I was able to create an executable using cx_Freeze but whenever I try to run the executable it runs without error but it cannot display any matplotlib figure. I have used Tkinter for my GUI. I have tried putting matplotlib backend as tkinter but figures are still not displaying.I cannot share the whole code as it is huge. Kindly Help.

Comment: I had a really hard time building an application that contained matplotlib in it with cx_freeze. I ended up having to just remove the plot portion of my code to build my application. It was only a minor part but just the same cx_freeze would not compile the matplotlib portion for some reason. I did try to get it to work over a few days but in the end I think cx_freeze just doesn't like matplotlib.

Comment: @Mike-SMT please see my answer for a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

The following example adapted from the `matplotlib` example [Embedding In Tk](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-user-interfaces-embedding-in-tk-sgskip-py) and from the `cx_Freeze` sample [Tkinter](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter) works for my configuration (python 3.6, `matplotlib` 2.2.2, `numpy` 1.14.3+mkl, `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1 on Windows 7).

Main script `main.py`:

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import math


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

# Data for plotting
i = range(0, 300)
t = [_i / 100. for _i in i]
s = [2. * math.sin(2. * math.pi * _t) for _t in t]

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, s)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window is closed with the window manager.
```

Setup script `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files': [
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))
         ],
        'packages': ['numpy']
    },
}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='matplotlib_embedding_in_Tkinter',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze matplotlib embedding in Tkinter script',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

Explanations:

- In order to freeze an application using `Tkinter` with `cx_Freeze`, one needs to set the TCL and TK library environment variables in the setup script, and to tell `cx_Freeze` to include the corresponding DLLs, see [KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35533803/8516269). The solution described there needs to be adapted when using `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1, see [Getting "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when using cx_Freeze even with tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll added in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52246748/8516269).
- `numpy` is required by `matplotlib` and it needs to be included in the frozen application even if the application itself does not explicitly use `numpy`. In order to include `numpy` in an application frozen with `cx_Freeze`, one needs to add `numpy` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe` option in the setup script, see [Creating cx_Freeze exe with Numpy for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10005533/8516269).

Comment: This method did not work for me. I had already followed these steps so maybe there is some other factor that is causing my compile issue. I hope it works for the OP though.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Which error do you get with the code of this post and what is your configuration?

Comment: @jpeg I have already made the changes that you suggested beforehand, cx_freeze is able to create an executable without error but the exe still can not display the matplotlib plots.