# transform python tkinter GUI to EXE file

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have been working on developing a GUI application using tkinter which is 100% working properly when running it from pycharm... and now I can't convert my script into an EXE file.

I have tried pyinstaller, cxfreeze and py2exe but everyone of them has a problem. pyinstaller show me 'Fatal error'... and cxfreeze seems to have a problem with MATPLOTLIB

Here are the libraries I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from math import sqrt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import beta
```

I don't want to post my code due to confidientality issues...
Does anybody has another idea ot do this ?

EDIT:
I reinstalled python as admin and reinstalled pyintaller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prOqZ.png)

and when I tried to convert the script here is the command error it shows:
['pyinstaller' is not recongnized as an internal command or external ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suh8E.png)

also I need to mention that the exe file of pyintaller in not founded in the directory of installation of python in C:programfiles/python37

Comment: pyinstaller should do just fine. what error do you get?

Comment: Please, don't post updates as answers. Edit you question instead. This time I moved the updated info into your question. Now you can delete your "answer".

Comment: It looks like you have multiple python installations. I would remove all python installations and do clear install. Make sure to add python to PATH. Here is nice tutorial https://python-forum.io/Thread-Part-1-Python-3-6-3-7-and-pip-installation-under-Windows Follow it verbatim

Comment: A solution working with cx_Freeze 5.1.1 (at least on my system) is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083651/8516269)