# KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze And DLL load failed

Tags: python, tkinter, dll, cx-freeze

I’m trying to convert from `.py to exe` using cx_Freeze
I made a `setup.py` code:

```
application_title = "Test_v_1.1"
main_python_file = "Test_V_1.py"
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base ="Win32GUI"

includes=["atexit","re"]


setup(
        name=application_title,
        version = "0.1",
        description ="Simle Test",
        options={"build_exe":{"includes":includes}},
        executables = {Executable(main_python_file, base = base)})
```

I add  the code below to my `setup.py  and got the error`
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\tcl\tk8.6'
```

I have tried to use pyinstaller but sins my cmd give me the error of `PyInstaller name not found` and my python don't want to uninstall pip 9.0.1 get stuck at the "uninstalling" phase I stared with a different way of converting my .py

Comment: `so.environ`? I assume it was just a typo?

Comment: Typo, My apologies

Comment: Please see [KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35533803/8516269) and [Getting “ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found” when using cx_Freeze even with tcl86t.dll and tk86t.dll added in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52246748/8516269). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811346/8516269) for a solution of both error messages you mention which should work for cx_Freeze 5.1.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyError: 'TCL\_Library' when I use cx\_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing the DLLs. Try include them in your setup config.

```
include_files = [r"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
             r"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]

setup(
        name=application_title,
        version = "0.1",
        description ="Simle Test",
        options={"build_exe":{"includes":[],"include_files":include_files}},
        executables = {Executable(main_python_file, base = base)})
```