# Convert tkinter file into .exe Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, tkinter, exe

This might look like a duplicate question, but I have pretty much gone through all other threads and couldn't get mine going, so here goes:

I have basically built a python 3 tkinter UI using text box, labels, images, buttons and I am trying to make this an .exe file. Now to try and test this first I made a skeleton tkinter code which is:

```
import tkinter 
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

I followed these steps from another stackoverflow thread:
(Top answer by Maria Irudaya)
[How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

My setup.py is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None    

executables = [Executable("tkinter_test.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna","tkinter"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "tkinter_test",
    options = options,
    version = "1",
    description = 'test',
    executables = executables
)
```

I followed these step by step and got a directory error for tcl tkl and I went past it by changing them to the Python35-32 directory, now the file is building but its not displaying anything. (It was supposed to open the blank UI with nothing inside it.) It opens and goes off in a flash. When I try to run it using cmd, I get:

```
C:\UI\tkinter_test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>tkinter_test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumsv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\kumsv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "tkinter_test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kumsv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I just want to convert my tkinter Python 3 file into a `.exe` file (Not necessarily by cx_freeze) so if someone has done it before with similar tkinter technicalities.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323533/when-using-cx-freeze-and-tkinter-i-get-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Zekii Thanks so much! BAM! It works.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `tk86t.dll` and `tcl86t.dll` files from your python directory's DLLs folder into the build folder with the `.py` you are trying to compile.

as per OP @Krishnakumar M's prior edit to the question.